# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'CityInfos' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I cannot make my form to work, I've tried a lot of stuff from different forums but cant find out how to do it

my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/board", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCityValues(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("CityInfos", new CityInfos());
    return "board";
}

@PostMapping("/board")
public String CitySubmit(@ModelAttribute CityInfos cityInfos) {
    return "board";
}
```

my class :

```
public class CityInfos {

    private String cityName;
    private String countryCode;

    public CityInfos() {}

    public CityInfos(String cityName, String countryCode) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }
}
```

and board.html

```
<form th:action="@{/board}" th:object="${CityInfos}" method="post">
    <p>Name of the City : <input type="text" th:text="*{cityName}" /></p>
    <p>Country code : <input type="text" th:text="*{countryCode}" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I just want to store the values of the input text inside my java class

Comment: You are having problems with the GET or the POST?

Comment: With the GET one

Comment: Change each `th:text` for `th:field`, on your inputs.

Comment: Now I have this error : `Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "board" - line 36, col 46)` which is the line of the first `th:field` occurence

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/board", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getCityValues(ModelAndView mv) {
    mv.setViewName("board");
    mv.addObject("CityInfos", new CityInfos());

    return mv;
}
```

Comment: thx for ur answer but I have the same error as i mentioned above